# Why does Date() function in javascript has a jerk when animating it

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have observed a serious thing in animating Date().
I face jerks whenever the Time, date, or year appear in animations.

I was creating a simple time showing webpage, and observed this.

If anyone knows, why that happens then please answer.

You can see my codepen here-
[Go to my codepen](https://codepen.io/zeeshaankhan/pen/abWBXgO)

```js
const d = new Date();
document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = d.getHours() + " : " + d.getMinutes();

function displayDate() {
        document.getElementById("date").style.width = "90%";
}

function reset() {
  document.getElementById("date").style.width = "0";
}
```

```css
* {
  background: #333;
  font-family: Lato;
}

.box {
  background: ;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 50%;
    height: 400px;
  margin: auto;
    position: relative;
}
button {
  background: #ccc;
  color: black;
  border: none;
  padding: 8px 10px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  font-size: 17px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#show-date {
  width: 30%;
  position: absolute;
    bottom: 30%;
    left: 35%;
}
#reset {
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
#date {
    color: white;
    background: #dd;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 80px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 0;
  display: block;
  margin: 10px auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: width 2s;
    animation-name: date;
  animation-duration: 4s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="box">
            <div id="date"></div>
      <button id="show-date"onclick="displayDate()">Show Date</button>
    </div>
    <button id="reset" onclick="reset()">Reset</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what do you mean ? when i klick on show date it shows hour and minute as i expect

Comment: The transition is jerky, at least on Chrome

Comment: for me the transition is exactly the same when i manually write sth. into <div id="date"> and remove the  .innerhtml stuff, so i guess it has nothin to do with date

Comment: You are not “animating the Date function”, that phrasing makes zero sense. You are animating the element `#date` (which happens to contain a date value you inserted dynamically, but that was before the animation even started. Had you put that same text content into the element statically, you would have exactly the same effect.)

Comment: You want to put `white-space: nowrap`. It's the text wrapping that causes the jank.  You just don't notice this because of your fixed height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system is adjusting word by word - because of the 'ordinary' spaces.

If you want spaces either side of the : then change them to use the HTML non breaking space in your JS:

```
document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = d.getHours() + "&nbsp;:&nbsp;" + d.getMinutes();
```

Comment: Or `white-space: nowrap`

Comment: @keith, thanks, yes it's nicer not to have to alter the JS.

Answer (score 2):

It was because of the space before and after `:` in your date

```js
const d = new Date();
document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = d.getHours() + ":" + d.getMinutes();

function displayDate() {
        document.getElementById("date").style.width = "90%";
}

function reset() {
  document.getElementById("date").style.width = "0px";
}
```

```css
* {
  background: #333;
  font-family: Lato;
}

.box {
  background: ;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 50%;
    height: 400px;
  margin: auto;
    position: relative;
}
button {
  background: #ccc;
  color: black;
  border: none;
  padding: 8px 10px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  font-size: 17px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#show-date {
  width: 30%;
  position: absolute;
    bottom: 30%;
    left: 35%;
}
#reset {
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
#date {
    color: white;
    background: #dd;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 80px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 0;
  display: block;
  margin: 10px auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: width 2s;
    animation-name: date;
  animation-duration: 4s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="box">
            <div id="date"></div>
      <button id="show-date"onclick="displayDate()">Show Date</button>
    </div>
    <button id="reset" onclick="reset()">Reset</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is not really a solution,  or the reason for the jank.

Comment: Well, thanks for your solution. This works fine, but this is not a full proof solution. 
Otherwise, it's fine.